# firebaseui localization in React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to localize the FirebaseUI in my React app.
When the user changes the language an action is dispatched. I am using middleware (currently redux-saga but I have redux-thunk there too).

I can't figure out how to change the Authentication UI to show localized button strings.

First I was using :

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui')
```

which was loading from node_modules.

Now I know I need to load a specific localized cdn for example if I want French. So I changed the app to have links to cdn in the index.html page and then use

```
var firebase = window.firebase
var firebaseui = window.firebaseui
let ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())
```

and then when they go to the login page:

```
ui.start('#firebase-auth-container',uiconfig)
```

However this obviously loads a specific language when the user gets index.html. How do I then change that cdn within the SPA React app?
I tried using react-helmet but

a) I don't think this replaces the original cdn, it just adds a new one

b) It doesn't work for me. I tried ui.reset() but that didn't seem to do anything.

Has anyone done this and can tell me how it should be done?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for doing the same thing. It seems [they suggest to load the localized widget](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#localized-widget) but I don't see an easy way to do this with dynamic languages.

Here's my solution inspired from [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/84#issuecomment-312284052):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  let providers = [{
      key: 'email',
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    },
    {
      key: 'google',
      provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    },
    {
      key: 'facebook',
      provider: firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    }
  ]

  providers.forEach(({
    key,
    provider
  }) => {
    let button = document.querySelector(`[data-provider-id="${provider}"] .firebaseui-idp-text-long`)
    if (button) {
      button.innerHTML = this.$t(`Sign_in_with_${key}`)
    }
  })
})
```